# [genie/vala]: How to Sort using a custom comparator?

Tags: vala, genie

genie!
how to Sort an array (or list) of strings in order of descending length, and in ascending lexicographic order for strings of equal length.

my data is

```
  datas : array of string = { 
    "cold", "z", "bpples", "pallalala", "apples", "xccv" 
    }
```

Comment: yes.it is not very clear

Answer (score 4):

Genie and Vala's built-in array type is not very friendly since it really a C array underneath. You'd have to use [C's `qsort`](http://valadoc.org/#!api=posix/Posix.qsort) function to do it.

I would recommend you use a `Gee.List` instead, which has a nice [`sort` method](http://valadoc.org/#!api=gee-0.10/Gee.List.sort) that takes a comparator:

```
var list = new Gee.List<string>();
list.add("cold");
...
list.sort((a, b) => - a.collate(b));
```

Here this list will be reverse sorted. By default, lexicographical collation (alphabetical order) is used. If you need an array at the end, use the `to_array` method.

Answer (score 4):

I can't help much with Genie, but in Vala it would be:

```
private static int main (string[] args) {
  string[] datas = new string[] { 
    "cold", "z", "bpples", "pallalala", "apples", "xccv" 
  };

  GLib.qsort_with_data<string> (datas, sizeof(string), (a, b) => GLib.strcmp (a, b));

  return 0;
}
```

Basically, the key is [`GLib.qsort_with_data`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.qsort_with_data.html).  You can also use [`Posix.qsort`](http://valadoc.org/posix/Posix.qsort.html) like apmasell mentioned, but it's a bit more difficult.

Like apmasell and txasatonga mentioned, you could use a datatype from libgee, but unless you're already using libgee you might want to go with something from glib instead.  In this case, [`GLib.GenericArray`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.GenericArray.html) would be a good fit.  In Vala, it would look like this:

```
private static int main (string[] args) {
  GLib.GenericArray<string> datas = new GLib.GenericArray<string> ();
  datas.add ("cold");
  datas.add ("z");
  datas.add ("pallalala");
  datas.add ("apples");
  datas.add ("xccv");

  datas.sort (GLib.strcmp);

  return 0;
}
```

One very nice thing about `GLib.GenericArray` is that it uses a C array as its underlying storage.  If you are using regular arrays in other places in your code you can access the underlying array using the [`GLib.GenericArray.data`](http://valadoc.org/glib-2.0/GLib.GenericArray.data.html) field and potentially avoid copying the entire array.  And, of course, it also doesn't force a dependency on libgee.

Finally, your choice of variable name…  'data' is plural, the singular of 'data' is 'datum'.  I only bring it up so I have an excuse to post [this](https://xkcd.com/1429/):

[image: XKCD 1429]

Comment: Hi! I want to know how to translate this line to genie. thanks.  GLib.qsort_with_data<string> (datas, sizeof(string), (a, b) => GLib.strcmp (a, b));

Comment: I found that finally!!  It is ugly, but works. thanks.qsort_with_data of string(...)

Answer (score 2):

```
uses Gee 
init
    a:list of string
    a= new list of string
    a.add("aa")
    a.add("ab")
    a.add("z")
    a.add("eas")
    // ordenar alfabeticamente
    a.sort()
    // ordenar la lista según la longitud
    for var x=1 to (a.size-1)
        for var y=0 to (a.size-2)
            var v1=a[y]
            var v2=a[y+1]
            if (v1.length < v2.length)
                var r= a[y]
                a[y]=a[y+1]
                a[y+1]=r
    for var i=0 to (a.size-1)
        print a[i]
```