# GLIb Array sort, how to sort?

Tags: arrays, sorting, glib, genie

I've tried to do some sorting with GLib's `GenericArray`, `Slist`, `List`. Sorting with `sort_with_data` works as expected, but when I've tried Glib's `Array` it doesn't work, or rather it does something different!

This is my sort function for integers:

```
[indent=4]

init
    var a = new Array of int
    for i in new array of int = {3, 2, 1, 5, 7}
        a.append_val (i)

    a.sort_with_data (my_func)
    for var i = 0 to (a.length - 1)
        stdout.printf ("%d, ", a.index (i))
    // 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 
    stdout.putc ('\n')

    a.sort (my_func)
    for var i = 0 to (a.length - 1)
        stdout.printf ("%d, ", a.index (i))
    // 3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 

def my_func (a: int, b: int): int
    return a - b
```

the output is
**3, 2, 1, 5, 7,**

I don't know what's wrong. Please don't tell me to use **Gee**!
my question is sort **Array of int**
Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[genie/vala\]: How to Sort using a custom comparator?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26572319/genie-vala-how-to-sort-using-a-custom-comparator)

Comment: You have now basically asked the same question *three* times. You should go back to the first question and edit it to show your progress or to add more details. Asking the same thing multiple times is not the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sort function for GenericArray is more easy to write.
but Array's sort function is different.

an example for sort int data, and sort string data

```
[indent=4]

init
    var a = new Array of int
    var b = new array of int = {3, 8, 6, 5, 7, 4, 1, 2}
    a.append_vals (b, b.length)

    // sort_with_data
    a.sort_with_data ((CompareDataFunc) int_sort)
    stdout.puts ("sort_with_data:\n")

    for var i = 0 to (a.length - 1)
        stdout.printf ("%d, ", a.index (i))
    stdout.putc ('\n')

    // sort
    a.sort ((CompareFunc) int_sort)
    stdout.puts ("sort:\n")

    for var i = 0 to (a.length - 1)
        stdout.printf ("%d, ", a.index (i))

    stdout.puts ("\nsort string:\n")
    // sort string
    var S = new array of string = {
        "zee", "app", "april", "bana", "grap", "oliv", "lim", "apri"
    }

    var T = new Array of string
    T.append_vals (S, S.length)

    T.sort ((CompareFunc) str_sort)

    for var i = 0 to (T.length - 1)
        stdout.printf ("%s, ", T.index (i))

    // app, apri, bana, grap, lim, oliv, zee, 

def int_sort (a: int*, b: int*): int
    return *a - *b

def str_sort (a: char**, b: char**): int
    return strcmp ((string)(*a), (string)(*b))


/* ouput

sort_with_data:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
sort:
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 
sort string:
app, apri, april, bana, grap, lim, oliv, zee, 

*/
```

Answer (score 1):

`a.length - b.length` will sort the strings by *length* not *contents*. If you want contents, use `a.collate(b)`.